# Camel's streaming mode vs Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, stream, apache-camel

I would like to ask if there is a similarity between Camel's stream mode, that is used by many components such as jdbc and Java 8 Stream.

Are these two the same thing? Can we take the stream created by Camel and process it like a Java Stream?

Thanks

Comment: In the Camel context "stream" always(?) refers the java.io type. Not to java.util.stream.

Comment: thanks for the answer

Comment: are you talking about: http://camel.apache.org/stream.html ?